# Create custom message box with no buttons and no minimize and maximize button

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to create a message box with no message box buttons and no minimize and maximize button, there just a close button. How do i do that?

Thank you.

I am confuse how to create that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a new `Form` with its `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` properties set to `false`. This will leave the close button only in the title bar.

E.g:

```
public class MyCustomMessageBox : Form {

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public MyCustomMessageBox() {
        MinimizeBox = false;
        MaximizeBox = false;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var messageBox = new MyCustomMessageBox();
messageBox.ShowDialog();
```

Create a label on your form and use the `Text` property to populate it.

Comment: Thank you very much! But, is that the minimize and maximize button still in there? They are just cannot be clicked?

Thank you though

Comment: They will still be there if you only set one of them to false. If both are false.. both should be gone (if I recall correctly.. its been a while since I've used WinForms extensively).

Comment: ooh yes, it is @Simon Whitehead, i never know that until you mention it. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 4):

Create a form and use it like a `messagebox`. Set its `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` properties to false. And invoke that form using `ShowDialog()`. I hope it would solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will play around with it somemore

Answer (score 3):

Create a form with name CustomMsgBox and paste following code.

```
public class CustomMsgBox : Form {
    private string _msg = string.Empty;
    public CustomMsgBox(string msg) {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        Button btn = new Button()
        btn.Text = "&Close";
        btn.Width = 80;
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Location = new Point(this.Width - (btn.Width + 50), this.Height - (btn.Height + 50));
        this.CancelButton = btn;
        this.AcceptButton = btn;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn_Clicked);
    }

    private void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

public class MyMessageBox
{
    public static DialogResult Show(string _message)
    {
        return Show(_message, string.Empty);
    }
    public static DialogResult Show(string _message, string _title)
    {
        CustomMsgBox msg =new CustomMsgBox(_message);
        msg.Text = _title;
        rturn msg.ShowDialog();
    }
}


CALL:

MyMessageBox.Show("This is a sample Text 1", "Hello World");
MyMessageBox.Show("This is a sample Text 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the Form property -> ControlBox = FALSE then it will remove Close and  Min,Max buttons that form  has.